# Laravel on AWS: APP_DEBUG not respected

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I initially deployed my Laravel app with APP_DEBUG set to `true`, but now we're in production I don't want it to whoops! every time there's an error.

I've changed the contents of our EB .config file so that `APP_DEBUG: false` and I can see the change in Elastic Beanstalk's environment properties:

[image]

But Laravel itself is still dumping everything to the screen when there's an error.

I've tried ssh-ing into our server and running `php artisan config:clear` to see if it was that, but it still didn't work.

I don't understand why Laravel isn't respecting the updated configuration on deployment. Can anyone explain the logic here?

**Update:** I updated the security settings on the instance and noticed that it was giving our custom error screen. Can anyone explain what happened? Was restarting the server after running `php artisan config:clear` what did it?

Comment: Can you change laravel `.env` file  `APP_DEBUG=false`.

Comment: I assume the problem lies int the `.env`-file as well, but can you try to ssh into the machine and run `php artisan tinker` and print out `config('app.debug')` (I think)

Comment: Interestingly I changed the security settings on the server and when I `tinker`ed into the instance to check the environment variable it had been updated. The site is now behaving as expected (ie. debug mode is off) however I still don't know what caused the change to suddenly recognized.

Comment: Don't install Whoops on public facing servers: `composer install --no-dev`. It's the only way to be certain your server credentials are safe...

Answer (score 0):

I had issues like this before where I changed something in the console's environment properties which did not correspont with what I got using tinker. You can find the env file on your instance here:
`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env`

if you open the file you see that variables set in .env are not quoted so if you have a password with for example a hashtag or a name with spaces it can result in unintended problems.

I would suggest to stop using environment variables via .yaml config files and start deploying your .env to the elastic beanstalk S3 bucket and fetching it on deployment. This will result in you having more control over the content of the file.

Example of this can be found here:

https://github.com/rennokki/laravel-aws-eb/blob/master/.ebextensions/00_copy_env_file.config